# how can I convert timestamp to date in mongodb and change the timestamp field with date?

Tags: mongodb

My base :

```
{
"_id" : 6038,
"name" : "Yaeko Hassan",
"gender" : "F",
"age" : 95,
"occupation" : "academic/educator",
"movies" : [
{
"movieid" : 1419,
"rating" : 4,
"timestamp" : 956714815
},
{
"movieid" : 920,
"rating" : 3,
"timestamp" : 956706827
}
]
```